# Emacs css-mode not loading

Tags: emacs24

I'm not sure why, but on my Emacs 24.3.50.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.8.4) css-mode is not loading and with M-x css-mode gives this error in Messages:

Symbol's function definition is void: apropos-macrop

or

File mode specification error: (void-function apropos-macrop)

my css file (ending in .css) is in Fundamental. I just tried it on a 23.1.1 and CSS mode comes up and works fine.

Update: Traced problem to my autoloads. i.e., comment out autoloads

```
;(load "~/modes/autoloads" 'install)
```

and the problem goes away. I'm not sure what to hack with an autoloads file. Any way to "step" through an autoloads? Here's my autoloads: http://gmcongo.org/temp/autoloads

Answer (score 4):

In Emacs 24.4 and the bleeding edge versions leading to it (like 24.3.50+), `apropos-macrop` has been replaced by `macrop`. In css-mode.el, replace the call to `apropos-macrop` with a call to `macrop` and the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the existing correct answer, you can create an alias in your `~/.emacs` instead of editing css-mode (if for example, it came in a package with your distribution):

```
;; For css-mode, temporarily.
(defalias 'apropos-macrop 'macrop)
```